# How to add social Icons in mobile navigation using elementor

Tags: wordpress, user-interface, themes, element, elementor

Is there any way to add social icon links in navigation for all the breakpoints using elementor in WordPress. I have managed to display them in a column on desktop but I am not able to display in mobile navigation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsjyT.png)

Comment: Can you show us what you have done so far ?

Comment: @jeremycastelli I have added image description. You can take a look.

Comment: I meant post your code

Comment: @jeremycastelli We haven't used code. This is displayed with elementor pro in WordPress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need icons to stay in a row with your logo(or any other thing) and not make a new row.

Well you have 2 options:

1. You can create a template (sections) and make put icons there, then add the template using shortcode widget. Just keep in mind, your section in header must have only 1 column and the widgets inside must be set to "inline".
2. You can have 2 or more columns and then add css class to each, then you will have to set "flex" in custom css. For example, you have columns with these css classes: .column1 & .column2

Now we go for custom CSS (doesn't matter on which widget you write this custom css):

```css
.column1 {flex:1;}
.column2 {flex:3;}
```

Change number in flex based on what you need.